# How can I list data in sections by an ID, with a while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a mysql table with these columns:

```
series_id, series_color, product_name
```

In the output I want to list the data in sections, with one section for each `series_id`, like this:

```
A12 Series Product

 - Milk  
 - Tea 
 - sugar
 - water

B12 Series Product

 - Water 
 - Banana 
 - Cofee 
 - Tea
```

Comment: You should show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to see all series a12 products with columns series_id and product_name?

Comment: @Luke101 I want show all series like my example. A12 series, B12 Series.... How many series have it should echo.. My php is not good maybe this is easy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order your results by `series_id`, so all the products with the same value will be together.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT series_id, product_name
                       FROM yourTable
                       ORDER BY series_id");
$stmt->execute();
```

Then when displaying the results, show the Series header and start a new `<ul>` whenever it changes:

```
$last_series = null;
echo "<ul>\n";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['series_id'] != $last_series) {
        if ($last_series) {
            echo "</ul></li>\n";
        }
        echo "<li>" . $row['series_id'] . " Series Product\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        $last_series = $row['series_id'];
    }
    echo "<li>" . $row['product_name'] . "</li>\n";
}
if ($last_series) {
    echo "</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```