# How to separate items rendered from .getJSON by category prop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtering

I've got a menu of coffee, for example, each with it's own `parentCategory` and I want to render them on the page like so but I'm not entirely sure where to start:

- category title

  - item
  - item
  - item
  - item
- category title

  - item
  - item

My data model looks like this:

```js
{ "menuItems": [
 {
    "index": 0,
    "parentCategory": "Americanos", 
    "calories": 234,
    "name": "Caffè Americano",
    "photos": {
      "squareThumb": "http://www.starbucks.com/assets/67c30b9dacd4406db797b1690ac22475.jpg"
    }
  }, {
    "index": 0,
    "parentCategory": "Lattes", 
    "calories": 234,
    "name": "Caffè Latte",
    "photos": {
      "squareThumb": "http://www.starbucks.com/assets/aee68ca3048142f38741f20b30b7a581.jpg"
    }
  }, {
    "index": 0,
    "parentCategory": "Mochas", 
    "calories": 234,
    "name": "Caffè Mocha",
    "photos": {
      "squareThumb": "http://www.starbucks.com/assets/bc15a5ca9d744b66bda07254f2f50013.jpg"
    }
  }...
```

and my current script looks like so:

```js
$.getJSON('menu.json', function(drinks) {
  var getMenuItem  = drinks.menuItems;
  var sortedArray = getMenuItem.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.parentCategory > b.parentCategory ?1 :-1
  })
  var output = "";
  for (var i in sortedArray) {
      output += "<div class='menuItem'><p>" + drinks.menuItems[i].name + "</p><img src='" + drinks.menuItems[i].photos.squareThumb + "'/></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=output;
});
```

Comment: Use nested `<ul>`. The outer list contains the category names, the inner list contains the item names.

Comment: Or use `<div class="category">` and `<div class="menuItem">`

Comment: Use a variable to hold the last category. In your loop, whenever the category changes, you close the old DIV and start a new one.

Comment: Here's an answer that shows how to do it in PHP. The logic is the same in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685

Comment: I've been trying for a half hour to translate this to JS but my rookie nature is making it near impossible. It's not entirely clear to me what logic is being communicated in this PHP above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the latest category in a variable. Whenever the category changes, start a new `<div>` for the category.

```
var last_cat = null;
var output = "";
for (var i in sortedArray) {
    var item = sortedArray[i];
    if (item.parentCategory != last_cat) {
        if (last_cat) { // close the previous category
            output += "</div>";
        }
        output += "<div class='category'><p>" + item.parentCategory + "</p>";
        last_cat = item.parentCategory;
    }
    output += "<div class='menuItem'><p>" + item.name + "</p><img src='" + item.photos.squareThumb + "'/></div>";
}
if (last_cat) {
    output += "</div>";
}
```