# Mysql Query for one group by column and display rest

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Table looks like this

```
component    maincomponent    subcomponent
5000         5001             5010  
5000         5001             5011  
5000         5002             5015
```

i want to display the result by using mysql query, or procedure, or function like this.  the data will be displayed in the html table so first row of the table will be: So every component, main and sub components will be displayed under the component.

```
Components:
5000
5001  
5010  
5011  
5002  
5015
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Your sample output just has one column, not 3.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, it's probably better done in whatever language you use to display the results, rather than in SQL.

Comment: in the first row i want to group fruits, second row group apple, third row sweet, than mango and than verysweet. i am using php and this is a table in which i can insert same values in col1 , col2 but col3 will be different. advice me if i want to do it in php

Comment: I dont want to query the database many times, i want to get the data once and display it on the view.

Comment: Query the database with `ORDER BY col1, col2, col3`. Then in the script that displays the results, show each column whenever it changes from the previous row.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685 for how to do it in PHP. The same general approach can be used in any language.

Comment: actually the link what you have given is some thing else i want to display the component, maincomponent, subcomponent. Componenet can be same because it is has category, and maincompnent can be duplicate but subcomponent will be different. component , maincomponent, subcomponent.

Comment: should i create one to many tables or single table.

Comment: I have got the answer what i was looking for SELECT component, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT maincomponent,'/n',subcomponent,'/n',text order by component) FROM `diagnoses` GROUP BY component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127336/discussion-between-muhabutti-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `UNION` operator. Using the data you've provided, you can do the following to achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT col1 FROM fruit
UNION
SELECT col2 FROM fruit
UNION
SELECT col3 FROM fruit
```

This will return the following:

```
fruit
apple
mango
sweet
notsweet
verysweet
```

Comment: This isn't the right order of results. `apple` should be followed by both of its `col3` values, and `mango` should be followed by its `col3` value.

Comment: If ordering is important, I agree with Barmar's comment above; Query the database and then use PHP to display things properly.

Comment: "SELECT component,maincomponent, GROUP_CONCAT(subcomponent,',',text order by component) AS st FROM diagnoses GROUP BY component")    Than in PHP $string = (implode(',',(array)$c->st));
                        $val = (explode(',',$string));
                        foreach($val as $value){
                        echo '<br>'.$value.'<br>';
                        }