# how to while loop inside of a while loop as well as grouping the result if more than one of the result are matching

Tags: php, mysql, database

The code provided is while-loop, which work, part of the loop is to update database and to return the updated info back to loop that work too. The problem I am having is if the return result is more than one it should not loop that result only echo it once.

I have tried other ways of doing this, but nothing giving me the result I need, I have the amount of knowledge I have on PHP. If someone could please help me, there help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
//////////////////////// non-spouse kid start ///////////////////////

$nonspouseKidSql=("SELECT * FROM familyTree WHERE memberEmail='$login_mem' AND familyRelationship='son' AND familySide='other' OR memberEmail='$login_mem' AND familyRelationship='daughter' AND familySide='other' OR fam
                                          ilyEmail='$login_mem' AND familyRelationship='father' AND familySide='other' OR familyEmail='$login_mem' AND familyRelationship='mother' AND familySide='other'");
$nonspouseKidQuery=mysql_query($nonspouseKidSql)or die ("error 1 Sorry we have a mysql error!");
$num_rowsNonspouseKid=mysql_num_rows($nonspouseKidQuery);
if ($num_rowsNonspouseKid < 1){echo '';} 
else{
    while($getnonspouseKidRow=mysql_fetch_array($nonspouseKidQuery)){
        $getnonspouseKidEmail = $getnonspouseKidRow['familyEmail'];
        $getNSPEmail = $getnonspouseKidRow['memberEmail'];
        $nonspouseKid_relationship = $getnonspouseKidRow['familyRelationship'];

        if($getNSPEmail == $login_mem){$nonspouseKidEmail = $getnonspouseKidEmail;}elseif($getnonspouseKidEmail == $login_mem){$nonspouseKidEmail = $getNSPEmail;}        

        $sql=("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$nonspouseKidEmail'");
        $query=mysql_query($sql)or die ("error 1 Sorry we have a mysql error!");
        $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $familyNonspouseKid_id = $row["id"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_firstName = $row["firstName"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_lastName = $row["lastName"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_email= $row["email"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic = $row["profile_pic"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_status = $row["status"];
            $familyNonspouseKid_gender = $row["gender"];

            if($nonspouseKid_relationship=="son"){$familyNonspouseKid_relationship ='son';}elseif($nonspouseKid_relationship=="daughter"){$familyNonspouseKid_relationship ='daughter';}      

            $member_familyPicNonspouseSon='/home/users/web/b2072/moo.poryniticom/profilePic/'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'/'.$familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic.'';

            if($familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic!==""){
                $member_familyPicNonspouseSon='<div id="connection_nonSpouseKid" class="connection_nonSpouseKid"></div><div id="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid" class="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid"><a href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.   
                    $familyNonspouseKid_email.'" id="'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img src="/profilePic/'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'/'.$familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic.'" style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;" 
                class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt="" /></a><div id="familyDisplayDiv'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="familyDisplayDiv" style="display:none">
                <table width="100%">
         <tr>
                 <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">Your '.$familyNonspouseKid_relationship.'</span></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
                 <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">'.$familyNonspouseKid_firstName.' '.$familyNonspouseKid_lastName.'</span></td>
        </tr>
                 </table>
                </div>
                </div>';
            }else{
                $member_familyPicNonspouseSon='<div id="connection_non-spouseKid" class="connection_nonSpouseKid"></div><div id="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid" class="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid"><a href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.  
                    $familyNonspouseKid_email.'" id="'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img src="/profilePic/default/default_profilePic.png"style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;" class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60" 
                height="60" border="0" alt=""/></a>
                <div id="familyDisplayDiv'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="familyDisplayDiv" style="display:none">
                <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                 <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">Your '.$familyNonspouseKid_relationship.'</span></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">'.$familyNonspouseKid_firstName.' '.$familyNonspouseKid_lastName.'</span></td>
        </tr>
                 </table>
        </div>
                 </div>';
            }                 
            $member_familyPicNonspouseDaughter='/home/users/web/b2072/moo.poryniticom/profilePic/'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'/'.$familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic.'';
            if($familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic!==""){
                $member_familyPicNonspouseDaughter='<div id="connection_nonSpouseKid" class="connection_nonSpouseKid"></div><div id="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid" class="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid"><a 
                href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.
                    $familyNonspouseKid_email.'" id="'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img src="/profilePic/'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'/'.$familyNonspouseKid_profile_pic.'" style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;"     
                class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                <div id="familyDisplayDiv'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="familyDisplayDiv" style="display:none">
                <table width="100%">
        <tr>
                 <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">Your '.$familyNonspouseKid_relationship.'</span></td>
                 </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">'.$familyNonspouseKid_firstName.' '.$familyNonspouseKid_lastName.'</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>';
            }else{
                $member_familyPicNonspouseDaughter='<div id="connection_nonSpouseKid" class="connection_nonSpouseKid"></div><div id="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid" class="memFamilyPic_nonSpouseKid"><a 
                href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.
                    $familyNonspouseKid_email.'" id="'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img src="/profilePic/default/default_profilePic.png"style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;" class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60"    
                height="60" border="0" alt=""/></a>
                 <div id="familyDisplayDiv'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="familyDisplayDiv" style="display:none">
                 <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                 <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">Your '.$familyNonspouseKid_relationship.'</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">'.$familyNonspouseKid_firstName.' '.$familyNonspouseKid_lastName.'</span></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                </div>';
            }                           
            if($familyNonspouseKid_relationship =='son'){echo $member_familyPicNonspouseSon;}else{echo $member_familyPicNonspouseDaughter;}
        }
        ?>
        <?php  
        //////// non-spouse kid end //////////////////////////////
        ?>
        <?php  
        //////////////// child parent not spouse start ////////
        ?>
        <div id="connection_childParent" class="connection_childParent"></div>
        <div id="memFamilyPic_childParent" class="memFamilyPic_childParent">
        <?php 
        $getGender = $mem["gender"];

        if($getGender=='male'){$parentGender='Mother';}else{$parentGender='Father';}

        $parentNameSql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM familyTree WHERE memberEmail='$nonspouseKidEmail' AND familyRelationship='mother' OR memberEmail='$nonspouseKidEmail' AND familyRelationship='father'")or die ("Sorry can't 
                                                                           get parent name!");
        $parentNameRow=mysql_fetch_array($parentNameSql);
        $parentName = $parentNameRow['familySide'];

        $childParentSql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM familyTree WHERE memberEmail='$login_mem' AND familyRelationship='childmother' AND child_Id='$familyNonspouseKid_id' OR memberEmail='$login_mem' AND 
                                                                familyRelationship='childfather' AND child_Id='$familyNonspouseKid_id'")or die ("Sorry can't get child parent!");
        $childParentRow=mysql_fetch_array($childParentSql);
        if($childParentRow < 1){echo '<p id="'.$familyNonspouseKid_id.'" class="mysql_returnNonspouseKid" align="center" style="color: #999; font-size:13px;">Child '.$parentGender.'</p>';
        }else if($childParentRow > 2){
            $childParentEmail = $childParentRow['familyEmail'];
            $familyChildParent_relationship = $childParentRow["familyRelationship"];       

            $childParent=("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$childParentEmail'");
            $query=mysql_query($childParent)or die ("error 1 Sorry we have a mysql error!"); 
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($childParentRow > 2){
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $familyChildParent_id = $row["id"];
                    $familyChildParent_firstName = $row["firstName"];
                    $familyChildParent_lastName=$row["lastName"];
                    $familyChildParent_email=$row["email"];
                    $familyChildParent_profile_pic = $row["profile_pic"];
                    $familyChildParent_status=$row["status"];         

                    $member_familyPicChildParent='/home/users/web/b2072/moo.poryniticom/profilePic/'.$familyChildParent_id.'/'.$familyChildParent_profile_pic.'';
                    if($familyChildParent_profile_pic!==""){
                        $member_familyPicChildParent='<a href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.$familyChildParent_email.'" id="'.$familyChildParent_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img src="/profilePic/'.$familyChildParent_id.'/'.      
                            $familyChildParent_profile_pic.'" style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;" id="memFamilyPic_border'.$familyChildParent_id.'" class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt="" /></a>';
                    }else{
                        $member_familyPicChildParent='<a href="headstoneViewMember.php?userName='.$familyChildParent_email.'" id="'.$familyChildParent_id.'" class="display_familyInfo"><img 
                src="/profilePic/default/default_profilePic.png"style="padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;" id="memFamilyPic_border'.$familyChildParent_id.'" class="memFamilyPic_border" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt=""/></a>';
                    }  
                }
                if($familyChildParent_relationship =='childmother' or $familyChildParent_relationship =='childfather'){echo $member_familyPicChildParent;}
            }}else{}
        ?>
        <div id="familyDisplayDiv<?php echo $familyChildParent_id; ?>" class="familyDisplayDiv" style="display:none">
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;">Your <?php echo $familyChildParent_relationship; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style=" font-size: 16px; color:#999999 ;"><?php echo $familyChildParent_firstName; ?> <?php echo $familyChildParent_lastName; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }}
///////////////// child parent not spouse end //////////////
?>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, but I suspect something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685) will be helpful.

Comment: The code provided is while-loop, which work, part of the loop is to update database and to return the updated info back to loop that work too. The problem I am having is if the return result is more than one it should not loop that result only echo it once.

Comment: I don't see anything that updates the database. The queries are all `SELECT`, not `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. It's really hard to see the structure of the code because of poor indentation. Can you reduce it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There's too much code here to understand it all, and I suspect most of it is repetitive and redundant.

Comment: @Poryniti How come question is related to `HTML` and `CSS`?

Comment: @Barmar I can't reduce it in more, everything I post is require for the code to function, update and insert portion of code I don't want to add more code that are not needed.

Comment: Your code isn't even valid. Somehow when you copied and pasted it here, you split lines in the middle of words. Look at the first query, where there's a line break between `fam` and `ilyEmail`.

Comment: @Barmar how doesn't that help?

Comment: How can incorrect code help understand the problem? I tried to clean up the indentation, but I'm not going to go through it looking for all the syntax errors you introduced when you were copying.