# php - mysql join three tables and grouping

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have three tables:

products:

```
id   name
1    juice
2    chips
3    water
```

orders:

```
id   product_id   order_id
1    1            special1
2    3            special1
3    2            special1
4    1            special2
5    2            special2
```

final_orders:

```
id   order_id   date
1    special1   25-3-2017
2    special2   25-3-2017
```

I want to select all products names in every order using order_id to show:

ID: Special1

Date: 25-3-2017

Products List:

juice

water

chips

ID: Special2

Date: 25-3-2017

Products List:

juice

chips

I use this:

```
$sql = "select * from products,orders where products.id = orders.product_id";
```

but it doesn't work and show me duplicated results.

thank you.

Comment: Do you want to include `final_orders` in the query?  What output do you want?

Comment: yes, it's the table that store orders ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see one final order per record in your result set, then you will have to aggregate the products which appear in each order.  One option then is the following query which aggregates order products into CSV using MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT t1.order_id,
       t1.date,
       t2.products
FROM final_orders t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) AS products
    FROM orders a
    INNER JOIN products b
        ON a.product_id = b.id
    GROUP BY a.order_id
) t2
    ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: thank you! but how can I select more data from products and orders tables? I have quantity (in orders), price (in products) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with `final_orders` as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM final_orders AS f
JOIN orders AS o ON f.order_id = o.order_id
JOIN products AS p ON p.id = o.product_id
ORDER BY f.order_id
```

To prevent duplication in the output, your loop that prints the output should only show the information from `final_orders` when it changes. See [How can i list has same id data with while loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685)

Comment: Even after you followed the instructions in the question I linked to?

Comment: yes

I get the same results when I use: 
select * from products,orders where products.id = orders.product_id

I think i should drop final_orders table and select all products name by joining products and orders and group results by order_id so I get for every code the name of products linked to it.

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Add it to the question.

Comment: I mean did you write the PHP loop that prints the results so that it only shows the order ID when it changes?