# Using Array & Foreach Together

Tags: php

I am looking for clarification on while loop and foreach loop...

say I have 2 tables both table have a field called MYID, MYID will be the same for both tables..

How would you accomplish echo certain fields once while another field multiple times.

example

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $MYID = $row['MYID'];        
        $FullName = $row['FullName'];    
        $Photo = $row['Photo'];        


    // Display this info once     
    echo "<div>$FullName<br>Photo</div>";   


   // Array for table 2 row    
   $Images[] = array($row['Images']);

   foreach ($Images as $img){       
   //Display this row as many times as needed by data in this row.

       echo <div>$img</div>;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add examples of input data and result you want/expect to get?

Comment: `$Images` contains all the images from all the rows you've processed so far, not just the current row.

Comment: If `$row['Images']` contains a comma-separated list of images, you should use `explode()` to split it into an array, and then loop over that.

Comment: example here I'm trying to create how each profile user there images is under there profile http://bodyelectrictattoo.com/our-team/

Comment: I want to create a profile page that displays just like that page with data from the database but the info will echo out the first profile 10 times for each image added.. and not other profile shows.

Comment: Are you joining a table with user information with a 1-to-many table of images? Then each image will be in a different row, unless you're using `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine them into one row.

Comment: You need to show sample input data and the query.

Comment: This answer should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685

Comment: @Barmar I don't use PDO, also I did do group_concat it wouldn't show images just the name of the image

Comment: What does PDO have to do with it? The general approach is the same with mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `GROUP_CONCAT`, `$row['Images']` will be a comma-separated list, which you can split with `explode()`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $MYID = $row['MYID'];        
    $FullName = $row['FullName'];    
    $Photo = $row['Photo'];        
    // Display this info once     
    echo "<div>$FullName<br>Photo</div>";   

    // Array for table 2 row    
    $Images = explode(',', $row['Images']);
    foreach ($Images as $img){       
    //Display this row as many times as needed by data in this row.
       echo <div>$img</div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: that work as needed but I only shows 1 profile now there are 2 in the database

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your query. Did you use `GROUP BY` properly? I asked above for you to add the query to the question.