# PHP PDO MySQL Populate HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bootstrap-table

I've searched and searched and I'm still pretty lost. What I struggle with is some basics, but I'm usually pretty good at figure things out from examples.

What I need help with: I can't seem to populate a Golf Scorecard HTML table based on my MySQL query. For whatever reason, I wish I knew, the last golfer in my table gets all the values. I can't figure our a way for the data to loop correctly. At hole 9, the loop should stop and move to the next row for the next golfer.

I've been trying Whiles and Foreach loops to figure out how exactly they work which is why I have both. I plan on combining the two queries into one, once I figure out the individual outputs.

I really appreciate any guides. I've been searching for a solution for a few weeks now, and I'm realizing I'm quite stuck.

[Current Golf Score Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYYDU.png)

---

### PHP PDO Queries

```
    //Get Hole Info
    $holeSQL = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT HoleNum, FrontBack FROM `tblHole` 
    WHERE CourseID=:course_id AND FrontBack=:front_back ORDER BY 
    `tblHole`.`HoleNum` ASC");
    $holeSQL -> 
    execute(array(":course_id"=>$courseID,":front_back"=>$frontback));

    //Get Par Info
    $parSQL = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT Par FROM `tblHole` WHERE 
    CourseID=:course_id AND FrontBack=:front_back ORDER BY `tblHole`.`HoleNum` 
    ASC");
    $parSQL -> 
    execute(array(":course_id"=>$courseID,":front_back"=>$frontback));

    //Get Round Scores
    $scoresSQL = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT tblScore.PlayerID, tblScore.RoundID, tblScore.HoleNum, tblScore.NumStrokes, tblScore.NumPutts, tblScore.FIR, tblScore.GIR FROM tblScore WHERE RoundID=53 ORDER BY tblScore.PlayerID ASC");
    $scoresSQL -> execute(array(":round_id"=>$roundID));
    $scores = $scoresSQL -> fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

### Array Output For $Scores

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 1
        [NumStrokes] => 5
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 2
        [NumStrokes] => 6
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 3
        [NumStrokes] => 4
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 4
        [NumStrokes] => 5
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 5
        [NumStrokes] => 3
        [NumPutts] => 1
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 6
        [NumStrokes] => 6
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 7
        [NumStrokes] => 7
        [NumPutts] => 3
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 9
        [NumStrokes] => 6
        [NumPutts] => 3
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 2
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 8
        [NumStrokes] => 2
        [NumPutts] => 1
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 1
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 11
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 2
        [NumStrokes] => 5
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 1
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 11
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 1
        [NumStrokes] => 5
        [NumPutts] => 3
        [FIR] => 1
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 11
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 8
        [NumStrokes] => 4
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 11
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 7
        [NumStrokes] => 6
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [PlayerID] => 11
        [RoundID] => 53
        [HoleNum] => 6
        [NumStrokes] => 6
        [NumPutts] => 2
        [FIR] => 0
        [GIR] => 0
    )
```

---

### Bootstrap Table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <!--<form class="tr" method="post" action="roundupload.php">-->
  <table class="table table-bordered m-b-0" id="roundupload">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Hole</th>
        <?php
        while ($HoleNum = $holeSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo'<th>'.$HoleNum['HoleNum'].'</th>'
        ;}?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Par</th>
        <?php
        while ($parInfo = $parSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo'<th><span class="label label-success">'.$parInfo['Par'].'</span></th>'
            ;}?>
          <th class="text-muted">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Pull in Shooter Names For Upload Table -->
      <?php
        foreach($arr as $userInfo){
        ?>
        <tr class="tableRow">
          <td class="text-muted" rowspan="1">
            <?php echo 
    $userInfo['user_first'].' '.$userInfo['user_last']?>
          </td>
          <?php
            ;}
            ?>
            <?php
            foreach ($scores as $holescore){
                echo'<td>'.$holescore['NumStrokes'].'</td>'
                ;}?>
            <td id="hole4:h4" class="inner strokes" contenteditable="true"></td>
            <td id="stroketotal:s1" class="inner-total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--</form>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$scores`?

Comment: There's nothing here that sets `$scores` to the scores for the specific player in the `foreach ($arr as $userInfo)`. So it's the same thing each time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for calling that out. I've added my query for $scores. I've also removed my original 2 array as they weren't related to my question. I've added part of the array I get when I query for $scores. @Barmar

Comment: Why does `$scoresSQL` need to join with `tblUsers`? It never uses anything from that table. And why does it use `GROUP BY` when it doesn't use any aggregation functions?

Comment: I can't see any reason why `$scores` only contains scores for `playerID = 2`. There's nothing in the query that restricts it to a specific player.

Comment: @Barmar Nice find. I removed the INNER JOIN and GROUP BY that was there back when I first setup the query. Must have just missed it since it wasn't causing an error. 

Also, I only posted some of the array. The full array is quite long. I added more so that you can see it does in fact move on the the next player.

Comment: I'm not sure if its easier if add my entire code or not. Please let me know.

Comment: Your loop that prints the contents of `$score` just prints the score, it doesn't print the player number. So how can you tell which player each score is for?

Comment: Perhaps this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685

Comment: It does indeed. I've also realized I can do this all in one query as well. I'll update my code with the working solution. Thank you sir.

Comment: Post it as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Get Round Scores Query. The query below allows me to get pretty much everything I needed in 1 query.

```
    //Get Round Scores
    $scoresSQL = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT tblUsers.user_first, tblUsers.user_last, tblScore.PlayerID, tblScore.RoundID, tblScore.HoleNum, tblScore.NumStrokes, tblScore.NumPutts, tblScore.FIR, tblScore.GIR FROM tblScore INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblScore.PlayerID=tblUsers.user_id WHERE RoundID=:round_id ORDER BY tblScore.PlayerID, tblScore.HoleNum ASC");
    $scoresSQL -> execute(array(":round_id"=>$roundID));
    $scores = $scoresSQL -> fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I had some help from a guy at work to help me understand how to create my own arrays to help with the data.

```
<table class="table table-bordered m-b-0" id="roundupload">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Hole</th>
        <?php
            while ($HoleNum = $holeSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo'<th>'.$HoleNum['HoleNum'].'</th>'
        ;}
        ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Par</th>
            <?php
            while ($parInfo = $parSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
               echo'<th><span class="label label-success">'.$parInfo['Par'].'</span></th>'
            ;}
            ?>
            <th class="text-muted">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Pull in Shooter Names For Upload Table -->             
    <?php
    $players = array();
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($scores as $result){
        if (!$players[$result['PlayerID']]['totalStrokes'] ) {
            $players[$result['PlayerID']]['totalStrokes'] = null;
        }
        if (!$players[$result['PlayerID']]['totalPutts'] ) {
            $players[$result['PlayerID']]['totalPutts'] = null;
        }
        $players[ $result[ 'PlayerID' ] ][ 'Name' ]    = array('first' => $result[ 'user_first' ],'last' => $result[ 'user_last' ]);
        $players[ $result[ 'PlayerID' ] ][ 'Hole' ][ ] = array('Hole' => $result[ 'HoleNum' ],'Strokes' => $result[ 'NumStrokes' ],'Putts' => $result[ 'NumPutts' ]);

        $players[ $result[ 'PlayerID' ] ][ 'totalStrokes' ] += ( $result[ 'NumStrokes' ] );
        $players[ $result[ 'PlayerID' ] ][ 'totalPutts' ] += ( $result[ 'NumPutts' ] );
        }

        foreach($players as $player){
            echo '<th class="text-muted" rowspan="1">'.$player['Name']['first'].' '.$player['Name']['last'].'</th>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['0']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['0']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['1']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['1']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['2']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['2']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['3']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['3']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['4']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['4']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['5']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['5']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['6']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['6']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['7']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['7']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['Hole']['8']['Strokes'].' | '.$player['Hole']['8']['Putts'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$player['totalStrokes'].' | '.$player['totalPutts'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Definitely not the best way to get the job done, but it did get the job done.