# Make query with non primary key table + add a row in middle?

Tags: mysql

So I have a 2 table like below:

Item

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| id |    Name    | Category    | 
+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Something1 |      A      |
|  2 | Something2 |      B      | 
|  3 | Something3 |      B      | 
|  4 | Something4 |      A      |
|  5 | Something5 |      A      |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Buy

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| id |    Name    |    Number   | 
+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Something1 |     14      | 
|  1 | Something2 |     10      | 
|  2 | Something1 |     14      | 
|  2 | Something5 |     11      | 
|  2 | Something3 |     12      |  
|  3 | Something4 |     18      | 
|  4 | Something3 |     11      |  
+-----------------+-------------+
```

The buy table don't have primary key because id forgein key with another bill table contain id and type(sell/buy/borrow). A bill can contain many items. I can join them one by one

```
+-----------------+-------------+
|STT |    name    |     Total   |
+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Something1 |     28      |  
|  2 | Something4 |     18      | 
|  3 | Something5 |     11      | 
+-----------------+-------------+
```

What I want:

```
+-----------------+-------------+
|STT |    name    |     Total   |
+-----------------+-------------+
| Category: A                   |
|-------------------------------|                             
|  1 | Something1 |     28      |  
|  2 | Something4 |     18      | 
|  3 | Something5 |     11      | 
| Category: B                   |
|-------------------------------| 
|  1 | Something3 |     23      |  
|  2 | Something2 |     10      |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Can it possible with just sql?(Not using temporary table)

Comment: Not sure I understand, sql only needs keys for performance purposes. A join on small tables will work fine without any.

Comment: yes. I can do group by and SUM but idk how to display those Category: ABCD one by one in a table and order them seperately.

Comment: @P.Salmon , *"MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an index is created. "*

Comment: @TrầnTrịnhKuy if he had the primary key, how would you have done it?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland true but not the thrust of the question I think.

Comment: @TrầnTrịnhKuy just like P.Salmon here i do not understand your question, the expected results looks like what should be done in the application, there is no way to get a header in between like that or i take the expected result (way) to literal

Comment: True @P.Salmon not sure why you then mentioned indexes then in your first comment annyhow... *"Can it possible with just sql?(Not using temporary table)"* it's the topicstarter not simply looking for a JOIN here..

Comment: I intend to query just once so I can print this out in this-> query($query). Not sure if possible to do so.

Comment: SQL can't return a table with different columns in each row, you can't have a category row like that. You normally do that in the application programming language that renders into something like an HTML table.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685 for how you can do it in PHP.

Comment: Many thank. That solved my problem