# Advanced/technical sorting of mysql records with php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am having an issue trying to determine how to sort some data from a mysql database.  I have a content items table, and the records contain an id (auto increment), a parent_id (so one page can  be a child of another), url, and title.

I want to sort the data in sort of a nested list style, where the main non-child page is first level, and those with that pages id as a parent id are listed below it.  Is there a special order to use here, or would this need to be sorted by php?

So, as an example:

```
id   |  parent_id  | title
---------------------------
1       0            Page 1
3       0            Page 3
6       1            Page 6
7       3            Page 7
```

The list should look as such:

```
Page 1
    Page 6
    Any others with parent id of 1
Page 3
    Page 7
    Any others with parent id of 3
```

Comment: You only want 2 levels, or additional nesting below that?

Comment: Do it using a self-join on parent.id = child.parent_id.

Comment: A 3rd level, I'm trying to understand how to sort this kind of data, if it canbe done via mysql or if i have to loop the results and sort them manually.

Comment: Hierarchical data in a relational database is not simple. The best way is using closure tables: https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql

Comment: When I had to do this for arbitrary number of levels, I did the sorting in PHP. You can write a recursive procedure to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For a table with 2 nested levels without any JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY IF(parent_id = 0, id, parent_id), id
```

Comment: Clever. You should mention that the line should be indented when `$row['parent_id'] != 0`

Comment: @Barmar, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with itself, joining the parent ID with the ID.

```
SELECT parent.title AS parent_page, child.title AS child_page
FROM yourTable AS parent
JOIN yourTable AS child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
ORDER BY parent.id
```

In your PHP loop, print the parent page heading whenever it changes. See [How can i list has same id data with while loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685) for the structure of that loop.