# combining multiple query results into one and I have different column name and displaying in HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

I have a table which keeps the record for letter send by different department to different region(A,B,C) in Hindi or English language as given in the table.

[image: Tblltr image]

I want to count the number of letter send by Each Department to Region A,B,C in Hindi And English as per the result table.

[image: Result table]

I am able to get this for all department together but not able to do is as per Department. Kindly guide me get that result.my query for all record. I tried cross join alias but not able to get it in given format.I tried multiple answer given here but no joy.

```
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="A" and Language="Hindi" 
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="A"and Language="English"
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="B" and Language="Hindi"
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="B" and Language="English"
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="C" and Language="Hindi"
select count(LtrNo) from tblltr where REGION="C" and Language="English"
```

Fiddle here [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/383f3f)

Answer (score 2):

Use a condition in `SUM()` to get the count of rows matching that condition, and then group by department and region. Use `WITH ROLLUP` to add subtotals.

```
SELECT IFNULL(department, 'Total') AS Department, 
    IFNULL(region, 'Total') AS Region, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(language = 'Hindi') AS Hindi,
    SUM(language = 'English') AS English
FROM tblltr
GROUP BY department, region
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to write the department once  (like merged cell)instead of multiple times

Comment: That's something you should do in your display application, it can't be done easily in SQL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575562/how-can-i-list-has-same-id-data-with-while-loop-in-php/27575685#27575685 for a PHP example.

Comment: THanks your answered works for me I was not having any idea about rollup